# Is reliable to use MAX(rowversion) as table wide data change indicator?

Tags: sql-server

In this application we have this users table that do not gets updated so frequently and we're planning cache this data in the client.

Is reliable to use the `MAX(rowversion)` value as an indicator of data changes in that particular table?

```
DECLARE @latestChange TIMESTAMP = 0x0000000000030D45
IF  EXISTS  (
    SELECT  TOP (1) 1
    FROM    MyTable
    HAVING  MAX(Version) <> @latestChange ) BEGIN

    SELECT  'Table has been changed, do stuff'
END
```

Comment: Id say using an id column would be better due to different timezones / collations etc

Answer (score 1):

Not in general.  If a row is deleted, the whole row, including the rowversion column is gone.  [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) will do this for you, without the need for a rowversion column.